# Script to delete files from multiple user paths from a list of computers?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, psexec

I wan to  write a batch script that can delete files from a specific folder for a bunch of users on that same computer. Not sure how this could work but I have this below of the idea of how it could work. I want to remote share in a pc, then navigate to all folders in the users folder then delete a text file in the specified path. How do I make this work?

```
@echo on
cd \\computername\C$
for /f "usebackq" %%m in (`dir /b \\computername\C$\users`) do (

del \\computername\Users\%%m\AppData\Local\folder\folder\Log\*.txt"
)
PAUSE
```

or

```
@echo on
psexec @pclist.txt -s cmd for /f "usebackq" %%m in (`dir /b \\computername\C$\users`) do (

del \\computername\Users\%%m\AppData\Local\folder\folder\Log\*.txt"
)
PAUSE
```

Comment: I have tried running both scripts but they output "cannot find file specified" or "cannot find path specified".

Comment: `cd \\computername\C$` won't work, but is not necessary anyway as you're stating absolute paths anyway consistently (but with a typo in the `del` command line though...)...

Comment: HEY!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Man I missed that typo, forgot the quote in front of \\. Thanks. It works now;

Comment: And yes, you are right I do not need cd \\computername\C$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both examples, you are looping over the `C$` share but not using that in your del command.

Try this:

```
@echo on
for /f "usebackq" %%m in (`dir /b \\computername\C$\users`) do (
del "\\computername\C$\Users\%%m\AppData\Local\folder\folder\Log\*.txt"
)
PAUSE
```

Comment: Yes this would be the correct thing for what I want to do, just don't need the cd \\computername\C$ and had typo in the del line, missed a quote in front of \\

Answer (score 0):

Since most native `cmd` commands are not capable of handling UNC paths properly, I would go for the following (assuming that the given UNC path is accessible):

```
@echo on
pushd "\\Computername\C$\Users"
for /F "usebackq" %%M in (`dir /B "."`) do (
    del ".\%%~M\AppData\Local\folder\folder\Log\*.txt"
)
popd
pause
```

`pushd` creates a temporary drive if a UNC path is given and makes its root the current directory. `popd` restores the previous state.

Comment: Cool didn't know about pushd, but in this instance it would not be required.